# Downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 7 Pro fails to install USB 3.0 drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, downgrade

I'm having issues to downgrade Windows 7 Pro from a preinstalled Win 10 machine. I already did a lot of research but couldn't handle it yet.

The main problem are the USB 3.0 drivers. When I try to boot from CD or USB, my mouse and keyboard stops working. I already checked my BIOS settings, especially there are only two options which I can turn off/on.

So I decided to do more research and found a way to inject drivers manually by mounting the "boot.wmi" & "install.wmi" plus using "cmd.exe".

At this time, I could finally use my mouse and keyboard. Setup finished to copy files and the regular stuff it does. So after rebooting the system I'm getting stuck at the screen where am I supposed to create an local account for further login process. It seems like that the drivers are vanished or something like that.

So the next thing I tried, was using an UBUNTU USB Stick, which works perfectly to have a look on my hard drive (SSD). I've tried to copy the specific USB 3.0 drivers into Windows/SysWow64/drivers and the other folder, but no changes after I rebooted...

My PC have USB 3.0 & 2.0, I tried both ports but didn't work out. Also I called Microsoft, but they couldn't help me. They told me to get a newer ISO of Win 7...

My Setup: Motherboard Name: ECS H110H4-CM2 BIOS Typ: AMI EFI

CPU: CPUID CPU Name Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz

USB: Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible-Hostcontroller -1.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a PS/2 keyboard handy?  Its a quick work around for problems with USB.

You should be able to install your USB drivers from your motherboard disc, navigating with your just your keyboard.

Comment: unfortunately no but I can try buying one if that's the only way :)
They didn't deliver a motherboard disc

Comment: Try disconnecting the power chord and press the 'on' button (to drain any residual current) and then reconnect the power chord and restart your system.  This sometimes works where a component is in some sort of failed state but isn't damaged.

Comment: Do you have a Windows 7 install disc.  When the installation starts, and you get to the 'install now' screen, select the 'repair this computer' option at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far guys, well I'll try that again. I do have both install mediums (USB & Disc).

Comment: Hi, I just did the steps you recommend me. But it didn't work. I'm getting stucked again at account creation :(

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)